# Is it possible to import an angular-6-generated library into angular 5?

Tags: angular6, libraries

Now that angular can finally generate libraries a bit more comfortably in version 6, are the libraries generated compatible to be imported in older versions, just like any other angular library?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library, as the new angular libraries probably function like any other upgraded library pack. If the libraries are included only in angular 6, then I would imagine that the libraries won't import into the older versioned app. If the library existed in angular 5 or older, then the library should import without any problem.

Other types of programming languages, like C#, Java, and Python, function this way, so angular would most likely work that same way, given its design with Typescript. Therefore, if the app returns a problem or error involving this, then you should upgrade the app to the newer version, and if the app is older than angular 5, upgrade the app one version at a time.

Comment: Well, my question was distinctly referring to libraries _created_ in ng 6 to be running in 5, and I am not talking about libraries that are included with angular, or third-party libraries specifically developed for angular 6, but about the relatively new feature in 6 that I, as a programmer, can create my own libraries, that live in the "libs" folder on the root level right next to "apps".
Basically, this feature uses ng-packagr, that was already available for 5, but a lot harder to implement, so my question was referring to a compatibility in format.

Comment: The reason why this question is of concern to me is, that I have an Ionic 3 app, which implements 5.2.2, and there is one part of a sort of an implementation of a Graph database construct, that I feel would be much better in a separate library. But I just worked through the setup for packagr, and it is a bit daunting in the Ionic context, I played around with it but couldn't get it to work on the first attempt. I have, however, already worked with 6 in my last project, and implemented lots of libraries, and it's very easy, so I am just trying to be lazy. Sigh, I guess I have to just try it ;-)